# PHP - associative array - blank row being added

Tags: php, codeigniter-2, associative-array, foreach-loop-container

I am trying to build Dynamic UI by getting data from DB using CodeIgniter but facing problem in constructing array.

**Requirement:**

Get parent menu items in an array. Then get child item corresponding to each parent item.

**Code to get data for parent element::**

```
$data['menu'] = $this->Menu->get_admin_menu_data();
```

This gives me 3 records

```
echo  "before loop menu" . count($data['menu']) . "</br>"; //prints 3
```

Now I run a foreach loop for each parent item to retrieve it's child item

```
foreach($data['menu'] as $menu){
   $data['menu']['menu_item'] =  $this->Menu->get_admin_menu_item_data($menu->ad_menu_id);
echo  "inside loop menu " . count($data['menu']) . "</br>"; //prints 4
}
```

As soon as I do this the count of menu increases to 4 resulting in error in UI.
I am new to PHP so now sure what is the best way to create a structure to hold this type of data.

Please help!!!!

Answer (score 1):

If `$data['menu']` contains **3 key/value pairs**, but `$data['menu']['menu_item']` is not set, your statement

```
  $data['menu']['menu_item'] 
     =  $this->Menu->get_admin_menu_item_data($menu->ad_menu_id);
```

sets just this.

Thus `count( $data['menu'] )` returns 4 elements afterwards - including the newly added `'menu_item'` key.

Comment: I think I asked the wrong question !! will post a new question with better detail

Answer (score 0):

I don't know CodeIgniter, but overwriting a static variable

```
$data['menu']['menu_item'] = "someting"
```

never makes sense. Where do you *really* want to store the result of

```
$this->Menu->get_admin_menu_item_data($menu->ad_menu_id);
```

? You can and should check the content of a variable using [var_dump](http://php.net/var_dump).